# How to return a string in C++ function

Tags: c++, c++11

I am reading the data from the file (Name color), and insert it into the table, and when the Name is matched, the proper color is returned.

How to return a string in function

```
class call_color
{
public:
std::map<std::string, std::string> table;

bool read(std::string &fname)
{
    std::ifstream ifs (fname, std::ifstream::in);
    if(ifs.fail())
    {
        printf("Cant open\n");
        return false;
    }
    return read(ifs);
}
bool read(std::istream &is)
{
    for (std::string line; std::getline(is, line);)
    {
        char *name = strtok(const_cast<char*>(line.c_str()), " \r");

        if(name != nullptr)
        {
            char *color = strtok(nullptr, " ");
            if(color != nullptr)
            {
                table[name] = color;
            }
            else
            {
                printf("No color %s\n", line.c_str());
                return false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            printf("No Name\n");
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
std::string get_color(std::string name)
{
   std::string color;
   std::map<std::string, std::string>::iterator it;
   it = table.find(name);
   if (it != table.end())
   {
    color = it->second;
   }

  return color;
 }
};
```

It returns a huge negative value(-772802864)  or a huge positive value for any Name. But I am expecting to get a string like: scdscsdcs

Comment: And your problem is.....?

Comment: `0` is not a valid string...

Comment: Throw an exception instead of returning 0?

Comment: the problem is still the same. it returns a huge value instead of something like that sdacdfsver243fc3refcvdfvd

Answer (score 1):

if you want to return an empty string you should add

```
return std::string();
```

at the end of the function.

Also note that your else clause contains a wrong return type. 0 cannot be converted to a valid std::string.

Answer (score 0):

This could help.

```
std::string get_color(std::string name)
{
    std::string color;
    std::map<std::string, std::string>::iterator it;
    it = table.find(name);
    if (it != table.end())
    {
        color = it->second;
    }
    else if (name == "Terminate")
    {
        color = '';
    }
    return color;
}
```

Comment: Did you try compiling your own, suggested, code? What sort of character `''` is meant to represent?

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with

```
table[name] = color;
```

The map `table` expects std::string objects both as key and value, but both `name` and `color` are char*. You should do something like this:

```
table[str(name)] = str(color);
```

Comment: What is mark? What doesn't work? Is there a compile error or do you keep getting strange results?

Comment: it is the same as color. typo.